# Merge Hashes in Perl: Special Case

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

How to merge two hashes in perl where keys can collide and the values are arrays.?
In case of collision I want to merge the value arrays.

Would normal merge be just fine?

I am sorry if this is a repetition, but I tried looking up but nothing such specific turned up.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to do it yourself. Iterate over one hash, look up in the other, merge arrays for each collision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To merge %hoa2 into %hoa1:

```
for (keys(%hoa2)) {
   push @{ $hoa1{$_} }, @{ $hoa2{$_} };
}
```

Comment: I like a concise solution.

Comment: Then you'll love `push @{ $hoa1{$_} }, @{ $hoa2{$_} } for keys(%hoa2);` :)

Answer (score 3):

The values of these hashes are array references.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

# The array ref of the first hash will be clobbered by
# the value of the second.
{
    my %hash_a = ( a => [ 1, 2, 3 ] );
    my %hash_b = ( a => [ 4, 5, 6 ] );

    @hash_a{qw( a )} = @hash_b{qw( a )};

    print Dumper( \%hash_a );
}

#  To merge the values of the arrays you'd need to handle that like this.
{
    my %hash_a = ( a => [ 1, 2, 3 ] );
    my %hash_b = ( a => [ 4, 5, 6 ] );

    @{ $hash_a{a} } = ( @{ $hash_a{a} }, @{ $hash_b{a} } );

    print Dumper( \%hash_a );
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => [
                   4,
                   5,
                   6
                 ]
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => [
                   1,
                   2,
                   3,
                   4,
                   5,
                   6
                 ]
        };
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Aside from the missing looping, that's not complete because it assumes the key exists in both hashes.

Comment: My answer is intended to illustrate how the data structure works. I wouldn't expect it to be a copy & paste solution. Am I missing the point?